# TKinter windows do not appear when using multiprocessing on Linux

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, multiprocessing

I want to spawn another process to display an error message asynchronously while the rest of the application continues.

I'm using the `multiprocessing` module in Python 2.6 to create the process and I'm trying to display the window with `TKinter`.

This code worked okay on Windows, but running it on Linux the `TKinter` window does not appear if I call `'showerror("MyApp Error", "Something bad happened.")'`. It *does* appear if I run it in the same process by calling `showerrorprocess` directly. Given this, it seems `TKinter` is working properly. I can print to the console and do other things from processes spawned by `multiprocessing`, so it seems to be working too.

They just don't seem to work together. Do I need to do something special to allow spawned subprocesses to create windows?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from Tkinter import Tk, Text, END, BOTH, DISABLED
import sys
import traceback

def showerrorprocess(title,text):
    """Pop up a window with the given title and text. The
       text will be selectable (so you can copy it to the
       clipboard) but not editable. Returns when the
       window is closed."""
    root = Tk()
    root.title(title)
    text_box = Text(root,width=80,height=15)
    text_box.pack(fill=BOTH)
    text_box.insert(END,text)
    text_box.config(state=DISABLED)
    def quit():
        root.destroy()
        root.quit()
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quit)
    root.mainloop()

def showerror(title,text):
    """Pop up a window with the given title and text. The
       text will be selectable (so you can copy it to the
       clipboard) but not editable. Runs asynchronously in
       a new child process."""
    process = Process(target=showerrorprocess,args=(title,text))
    process.start()
```

---

**Edit**

The issue seems to be that `TKinter` was imported by the parent process, and "inherited" into the child process, but somehow its state is inextricably linked to the parent process and it cannot work in the child. So long as you make sure not to import `TKinter` before you spawn the child process, it will work because then it is the child process that is importing it for the first time.

Comment: Does it get the needed environment?

Comment: I don't mind the edits to break this into more paragraphs, but some of these punctuation edits are actually breaking the grammar and making it harder to read. Is there a reason for all these minor tweaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [discussion](http://pyinsci.blogspot.com/2008/09/python-processing.html) could be helpful.

> Here's some sample problems I found:
>
> 1. While the multiprocessing module follows threading closely, it's definitely not an exact match. One example: since parameters to a
>      process must be *pickleable*, I had to go through a lot of code
>      changes to avoid passing `Tkinter` objects since these aren't
>      *pickleable*. This doesn't occur with the threading module.
> 2. `process.terminate()` doesn't really work after the first attempt. The second or third attempt simply hangs the interpreter, probably
>      because data structures are corrupted (mentioned in the API, but this
>      is little consolation).

Comment: Aha! You gave me an idea. My main process has no need of Tkinter, so I moved the line importing all the tkinter stuff into showerrorprocess and it worked! I guess that multiprocessing must have pickled up all of the state in the Tkinter module. I wonder how to stop it from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe calling the shell command `xhost +` before calling your program from that same shell will work?

I am guessing your problem lies with the X-server.

Comment: I gave it a shot, but no luck.