# Tkinter multiprocessing: the main GUI window is not displayed

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am new to python and trying to implement multiprocess with Tkinter. I am having a main GUI process, with two other "test" processes. This code works fine in Windows, and the main window is displayed and the other two processes are also running. However when I run this code in Ubuntu, it does not work, the two test processes are running but the main GUI window is not displayed.
Can anyone help me on this?

```
from Tkinter import *   
from multiprocessing import Process  
import time
def mywind():
      root=Tk()    
      root.title = "MyWindow"  
      frame=Frame(root)  
      root.mainloop()
def test1():   
    while True:    
        print  "In test1"    
        time.sleep(1)    

def test2():    
    while True:   
        print  "In test2"    
        time.sleep(1)    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p1 = Process(target=test1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=test2)
    p2.start()
    p = Process(target=mywind)
    p.start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't TKinter windows appear when using multiprocessing on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410469/why-dont-tkinter-windows-appear-when-using-multiprocessing-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from Tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

root = None

def mywind():
    root=Tk()
    root.title = "MyWindow"
    frame=Frame(root)
    return root

def test1():
    while True:
        print  "In test1"
        time.sleep(1)

def test2():
    while True:
        print  "In test2"
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p1 = Process(target=test1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=test2)
    p2.start()
    root = mywind()
    root.mainloop()
```

I can't perfectly explain why putting the main loop into the main process rather than a subprocess works. I assume it has something to do with the way `Tk` resources (and underlying native windowing resources) are managed by the `Tkinter` library, and collisions with the idea of running them in a separate process.